# Is it possible to load a php file without a selector?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I need to load a file but without a selector, is it possible?

```
$("???").load("file.php");
```

Comment: `load()` implies "loading" into something. If you're simply trying to get the `file.php` try using `$.ajax()` or `$.get()`

Comment: `load()` is a shortcut for `$.ajax` with a specific use case. There are other shortcuts and the main `$.ajax` itself. Not hard to look this up in the API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yea, you just call ajax. The prior jQuery selector is telling it to load the returned content into that selector item. To plain just call it, use the following:

```
$.ajax({ 
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```